# Foundry errors due to imports not being correct, but they have been remapped - how do I get Foundry to acct for the remappings so it will compile?

Tags: foundry

I have been trying to compile a github that I cloned using Foundry. The github has a remappings.txt and the contracts in the github use the remappings in that remmapings.txt file. But when I run forge build I get errors that the imports are incorrect (because foundry isn't taking the remappings into account).

I manually changed all the imports but then I realized that messed up other parts....I assume there must be some way to get foundry to take the remappings.txt file into account while it is compiling? It seems like, since it is processing the files from top to bottom, and the remappings.txt is one of the last files, it is not applying the remappings as it checks the contracts for errors (all the imports are underlined with red).

I'm on vscode

Comment: Maybe you didn't refresh the submodules, check out my [reinit](https://twitter.com/PaulRBerg/status/1629425771457531905) subcommand